# af_setImage - unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to load my images from sever side, but `af_setImage` show me this error :

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

my code :

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SupportersCollectionViewCell


    let url_img = URL(string: self.titles[indexPath.row])!

    print(url_img)//it returns correct value like http://kashanmap.ir/images/apk_images/hamian/hamian2.png

    cell.img_main.af_setImage(
        withURL: url_img
    )


    return cell
}
```

my custom cell:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage
class SupportersCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var img_main: UIImageView!
}
```

[image]

updated

my image view returns null:

if(cell.img_main == nil)
        {
            print("test")
        }

Comment: Cell's  @IBOutlet img_main is connect to the Interface Builder widget?

Comment: yes. it is connected.

Comment: Assuming `af_setImage` is a `UIImageView!`, My guess is it's not properly connected to the nib.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
    cell.img_main.image = nil

    if let url_img = URL(string: self.titles[indexPath.row])
    {
       cell.img_main.af_setImage(withURL: url_img)
    }
    else
    {
        print("error!")
    }
```

That way an error doesn't crash your app.

Answer (score 0):

We observed similar issue and after much debugging we found that the server was returning the content type = "image/*". It was not acceptable to AlamofireImage and it was returning nil response.

We could get around this problem by using '**ImageResponseSerializer**' :

```
 var imgSer = ImageResponseSerializer.self
        imgSer.addAcceptableImageContentTypes(Set(arrayLiteral: "image/*"))
        mView!.af.setImage( withURL: url, 
                placeholderImage: mPlaceholderImage, 
                **serializer: imgSer.init()**, 
                filter: self, 
                progress: nil,  imageTransition: imgTransition!, runImageTransitionIfCached: true, completion: { dr in  .....
```

AlamofireImage (3.6.0), Alamofire (4.9.1)